# How to use Python to log in website with popping out window

Tags: python, authentication, web

I have encountered a problem which is to use Python to log in a website. However, the website login is a popping out window, hence I don't know how to use Python to put in my login info.

So my aim is to download some data from the website which requires a logging in first. Previously the main page has a fixed area for inputs, so I used requests, and beautiful soup. Now the log in becomes a pop-out window which needs an "onclick" in its source code..

Previous sol.:

```
import requests, pandas as pd
import win32com.client
import datetime as date
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload = {
    'action': 'client_login/client_authorise.asp?action=login',
    'companyName': XXX,
    'username': XXX,
    'password': XXX
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post('http://www.mywebsite.com/', data = payload)
    raw_cape = s.get('http://www.mywebsite.com/the page has my data/')
```

Source code for log-in window:

```
<table class='btn' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='margin-top:5px;' onclick="_infx.baltic.login.dialog();">
                        <tr>
                            <td class='l'><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt='' style='width:6px;border:0px;'/></td>
                            <td class='m'>Login</td>
                            <td class='r'><img src="/images/spacer.gif" alt='' style='width:6px;border:0px;'/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Now part of the source code (not sure if this is helpful):

```
<p style='font-size:12px;line-height:16px;margin-bottom:8px;margin-top:8px;padding-left:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;width:535px;padding:6px;background-color:#eee;border-radius:4px;'><b>_domain</b> - Remembers your login domain preference.</p>
                    <p style='font-size:12px;line-height:16px;margin-bottom:8px;margin-top:8px;padding-left:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;width:535px;padding:6px;background-color:#eee;border-radius:4px;'><b>_company_id</b> - Remembers your login company id.</p>
                    <p style='font-size:12px;line-height:16px;margin-bottom:8px;margin-top:8px;padding-left:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;width:535px;padding:6px;background-color:#eee;border-radius:4px;'><b>_company_name</b> - Remembers your login company name.</p>
                    <p style='font-size:12px;line-height:16px;margin-bottom:8px;margin-top:8px;padding-left:0px;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;width:535px;padding:6px;background-color:#eee;border-radius:4px;'><b>_username</b> - Remembers your login username.</p>
```

Comment: This is going to depend somewhat on how your code is interacting with the website, and how the website handles the authentication.  Can you provide any more information about how you're trying to do this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have edited my post to show more details.. Pls take a look..

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do unittest? You can use selenium to do stuff like this.

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html

Comment: Thanks tho I haven't used this before... I'm reading this now.